# Not Able to see messages for particular intents [Chatbase]

Tags: chatbot, chatbase

We just started integrating Chatbase for one of our Bot's and I'm sending messages to Chatbase, but I'm not able to view messages for specific intents on the dashboard. The specific case pertains to messages which are related to dates.

Here is a curl request.

```
curl -X POST \
  https://chatbase-area120.appspot.com/api/message \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'postman-token: f82cc2de-4514-8055-c28e-8746fce002c9' \
  -d '{
            "api_key": "xxxxxxxx",
            "type": "user",
            "platform": "mobile",
            "message":"19-06-2017",
            "intent": "EndDate",
            "version": "1.0",
            "user_id": "user-26",
            "time_stamp": "1515492147",
            "not_handled": false
          }'
```

This is the view in the dashboard.
[image: Not able to see date]

Also, I find it strange that the messages for another intent show up correctly on the dashboard.

[image]

Is there a format in which date has to sent to Chatbase for it to be shown on the dashboard? By the way, this happens with other intents also which are related to mobile numbers, email, and address.

Answer (score 2):

I am Sean from Chatbase customer support.  Thank you for your detailed question and interest in Chatbase.

We filter message content that may be used to identify a particular person, such as an account number, phone number, email address, or SSN. It looks like your date formats are being confused with SPI (sensitive personal information). I have raised the issue with our backend development team and will respond as soon as we have a solution for you.

Thank you.